# Stored procedure only executes correctly on first execution

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've written this SQL Server stored procedure that inserts records into another table based on the order frequency of customers in another table. It assigns a rank to each customer based on their order frequency. When I create the procedure and execute it for the first time, it works fine and inserts the correct records into the table. But when I clear the table and try to execute the procedure again, no records are added. I have to delete the procedure, restart SSMS, and create the procedure again for it to work correctly again.

Here is the procedure:

```
create procedure TopKCustomer (@CustRank decimal(11,0))
as
    declare CustCursor cursor local for
        select o.CustomerID,c.CustomerName,c.CustomerPostalCode,
            count(o.CustomerID) as 'Order Frequency'
        from (Customer_T c join Order_T o on c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID) 
        group by o.CustomerID,c.CustomerName,c.CustomerPostalCode
        order by [Order Frequency] desc;

    declare @PrevOrderFreq float;
    declare @CurrOrderFreq float;
    declare @CurrRank decimal(11,0);
    declare @CurrCustID decimal(11,0);
    declare @CurrCustName varchar(25);
    declare @CurrCustPostCode varchar(10);

begin
    set @PrevOrderFreq = 0;
    set @CurrOrderFreq = 0;
    set @CurrRank = 0;
    set @CurrCustID = 0;
    set @CurrCustName = '';
    set @CurrCustPostCode = '';

    open CustCursor;

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        fetch next from CustCursor into @CurrCustID, @CurrCustName, @CurrCustPostCode, @CurrOrderFreq;

        if @CurrOrderFreq <> @PrevOrderFreq
        begin
            set @CurrRank = (@CurrRank + 1);

            if @CurrRank > @CustRank
            begin
                break;
            end
        end

        insert into TopKCustomer_T
        values (@CurrCustID, @CurrCustName, @CurrCustPostCode, @CurrRank, getdate());

        set @PrevOrderFreq = @CurrOrderFreq;
    end

    close CustCursor;
    deallocate CustCursor;
end
```

Here are the tables I'm working with:

- Customer_T (CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerCity, CustomerState, CustomerPostalCode)
- Order_T (OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate)
- TopKCustomer (CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerPostalCode, CRank, RankGenerateDate)

Comment: Wow....cursor.  Why???  SQL is a set based language.  You don't loop each record one by one.

Comment: Is the cursor causing the problem?

Comment: You can Google it.  It's not the right way to loop records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is

```
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
```

This will be result of the previous fetch (in other words the fetch from the previous execution of your stored procedure, not what you want).

The usual way I wrote cursor loops is

```
while 1 =1 
begin
  fetch next from c into ...
  if @@fetch_status != 0 break 
  ...
end
```

Comment: would simply moving the cursor declaration from just after the "as" until just after the first "begin" possibly fix it?

Comment: @Kevin There are lots of ways to fix it, this "while 1=1" method means you don't have to write the fetch more than once, which I think is  neater especially if you have a lot of variables to fetch into, as here.

Answer (score 1):

There's no sample data or table structure so I don't know what your data looks like.  Below is what I think you want.  The inner query count the order per customer.  The outer query rank them.

```
SELECT *
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderFrequency) AS Rnk
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY o.CustomerID) AS OrderFrequency
    FROM Customer_T c 
    JOIN Order_T o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
) a
```