# How to loop a SELECT statement on a list of tables in Azure Synapse using Dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, azure-synapse

I often have to find out what is the latest date of a record count of multiple tables. Currently I'm trying to find out the maximum loaddate from a list of tables.

I have the below list of example tables:

```
TableA
TableB
TableC
TableD
```

So far I'm able to declare a variable and pass the single table name as a parameter into my SQL statemen as follows:

```
DECLARE @SQLstmnt varchar(500)
 
DECLARE @tname varchar(200)
SET @tname = 'TableA'
 
SET @SQLstmnt = 'SELECT MAX(loaddate) FROM ' + @tname
 
EXEC (@SQLstmnt)
```

But I don't know how to pass my entire table name list `(TableA, TableB, TableC, TableD)` and loop the above SELECT statement on each of those tables in the list.

I searched for a solution but I just don't seem to find the one that suits my case.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a dynamic union query for all tables and execute it this way:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT  @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT TableName, Date FROM (',
                STRING_AGG(CONCAT('SELECT TableName = ''', t.Name, ''',  Date = MAX(', c.name, ') 
                                  FROM ', QUOTENAME(s.name), '.', QUOTENAME(t.name)), ' UNION ALL '),
                ') AS t;')
FROM    sys.columns AS c
        INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
            ON t.object_id = c.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
            ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE   c.name = 'LoadDate' -- Check Column Exists
AND     t.name IN ('TableA', 'TableB', 'TableC', 'TableD') -- Limit to required tables;
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0

PRINT @sql
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

This will build a SQL Statement something like this for your example:

```
SELECT TableName, Date 
FROM (SELECT TableName = 'TableA',  Date = MAX(LoadDate) FROM dbo.TableA
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT TableName = 'TableB',  Date = MAX(LoadDate) FROM dbo.TableB
     UNION ALL
     SELECT TableName = 'TableC',  Date = MAX(LoadDate) FROM dbo.TableC
     UNION ALL
     SELECT TableName = 'TableD',  Date = MAX(LoadDate) FROM dbo.TableD
    ) AS t;
```

And return all tables/dates as a single set:

If you really did want to iterate over the tables then I would still use the system views as a starting to point to verify that (a) the table exists and (b) contains the load date column, but use a [`CURSOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to execute the statement against each table rather than building a single statement:

```
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT  CONCAT(QUOTENAME(s.name), '.', QUOTENAME(t.name))
    FROM    sys.columns AS c
            INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
                ON t.object_id = c.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
                ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE   c.name = 'LoadDate'
    AND     t.name IN ('TableA', 'TableB', 'TableC', 'TableD') -- Limit to required tables;

DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME;
OPEN TableCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT('SELECT TableName = ''', @TableName, ''', Date = MAX(LoadDate) FROM ', @TableName);

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName;

END

CLOSE TableCursor;
DEALLOCATE TableCursor;
```

Comment: Nice... although I much prefer this cursor pattern [shown in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61279243/1127428)

Answer (score 1):

Super simple... just use a `WHILE` loop

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE ([Name] varchar(256), Done bit default(0));

INSERT INTO @MyTable ([Name])
VALUES
('TableA'),
('TableB'),
('TableC'),
('TableD');

DECLARE @SQLstmnt nvarchar(max), @tname varchar(200);

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @MyTable WHERE Done = 0) BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @tname = [Name]
    FROM @MyTable
    WHERE Done = 0;
  
    SET @SQLstmnt = 'SELECT MAX(loaddate) FROM ' + @tname + ';';
 
    -- This is the best practice way to execute dynamic SQL
    -- EXEC sp_executesql @SQLstmnt;
    -- Debug the dynamic SQL
    PRINT(@SQLstmnt);

    UPDATE @MyTable SET Done = 1 WHERE [Name] = @tname;
END;
```

Comment: I keep getting an error on line 1 at TABLE: `Parse error at line: 1, column: 18: Incorrect syntax near 'TABLE'.` What am i missing?

Comment: A typo on your part? That query is working see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AGUkBcYU)

Comment: "Parse error at line: 1, column: 18" sounds like you are using Synapse data warehouse product. You should always tag that as supported Syntax is much less than other editions.

Comment: @MartinSmith Indeed, I'm connecting to Azure Synapse from SSMS v18.9.1

Comment: @LearneR you do need to be specific about the RDBMS you are using... they are all different.

Comment: @LearneR but just convert the table variable to a temp table...

Comment: @LearneR SSMS and its version are irrelevant... its just a client UI... what is important is the database engine, and its version.

Comment: @DaleK - sorry my bad! Will try with a temp table as suggested.

Comment: The other answer might be a better fit?

Comment: @DaleK - apologies for late response. Indeed you're right, the other answer was able to help my situation. Thank you very much. And special thanks for the dbfiddle link. I didn't know of this service previosly. Looks supercool.